# Center grid item on wrap

Tags: html, css, css-grid, centering

I am trying to figure out how to center a a 3rd div. So on full width i have 3 boxes in a grid. They are 400px in width. When the width is 1220px that turns into 2 boxes in a row. So my 3rd box is aligned to the left. How do i center it without ruining the width. Because i tried `margin: 0 auto` and it just made it as wide as the stuff inside it.

here is my code:

```css
.wraper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 400px 400px 400px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 400px);
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}

@media (max-width: 1220px) {
  .wraper {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 400px);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 810px) {
  .wraper {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 400px);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .wraper {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 300px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block bg-success">
  <h1>Projects</h1>
  <div class="wraper">
    <div class="box">A</div>
    <div class="box">B</div>
    <div class="box">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is falling within the `wraper` box so it has an imaginary 4th box there blocking it.

Comment: @Mech how can i fix it then?

Comment: Just a friendly suggestion: The correct spelling is "wrapper".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 1220px media query, add a rule to center the third div.

```
@media (max-width: 1220px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 400px);
  }

   /* NEW */
  .box:last-child {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    justify-self: center;
    width: 400px;
  }
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8tg4ycwr/3/)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 400px 400px 400px;
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;  
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 400px);
}

@media (max-width: 1220px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 400px);
  }

   /* NEW */
  .box:last-child {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    justify-self: center;
    width: 400px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 810px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 400px);
  }

   /* RESET */
  .box:last-child {
    grid-column: auto;
    justify-self: stretch;
    width: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 300px);
  }
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block bg-success">
  <h1>Projects</h1>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">A</div>
    <div class="box">B</div>
    <div class="box">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay i tried that but now when i scale down to one coloumn its all weird how do i default everything back?

Comment: Look at the full code snippet I posted. It includes the reset for the following media queries.

Comment: Oops didnt see that but thank you for your help you are a life saver